# MDS Application Pool : Incorrect Password

Tags: sql-server, iis, master-data-services

I am trying to create the MDS website and for the Application Pool I am using my Windows 10 Domain\user and password (home computer). I keep getting the following error: "the password supplied is incorrect". I know the password is good as I logged into my laptop. I am also local admin. I tried to create a new website and Application Pool as well as use the DefaultWebSite.

The default app pool security is to "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

What else need I do

Comment: What kind of "MDS website"? And also please show a screen shot of the error.

Comment: Master Data Services : MSSQL 2017. the configuration web site. It works on a networked server, why not on a windows 10 laptop

Comment: It would be an MDS specific error, so I edited the tags. You might also show at which step the error message occurs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/master-data-services-installation-and-configuration?view=sql-server-2017#SetUpWeb